# what family of distributions is this?

Tags: probability-distributions

I want to know what type of family this distribution belongs to:

- The variable is $x$.
- There is a parameter $\alpha$ with $\alpha>0$
- There is a constant $H > 0$.
- The *pdf* is

$$
f(x,\alpha) = \frac{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}}{\left[H\bigg(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha}\bigg)\right]^{\alpha}}
$$

- The distribution support is $[0,H\big(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha}\big)]$.

For example, if $\alpha=1$, $f(x,1)$ becomes the Uniform distribution. If $\alpha \to \infty$, $f(x,\infty)$ degenerates at $H$.

I want to know the name of the family (if it exist) so I can learn more about its moments, etc. I have not found it online so far.

Comment: some sort of power law distribution maybe?

Comment: Without specifying what $H$ is, or its properties, $H(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha})$ appears to say nothing. If you want a finite domain of support, set the upper bound to $c$, and solve  $P(X<c) == 1$ for $c$ as a function of $\alpha$.

Comment: H is a constant. Not really relevant to the problem. Added to the question.

Comment: This is a good source of distributions but I have not checked it for yours. http://www.causascientia.org/math_stat/Dists/Compendium.pdf

Comment: My bad, I made a terrible mistake. Formula updated. Well, if you take away all the constant/parameters stuff it is basically $f(x,k)=c(k)x^{k}$ and so I guess it is indeed a power law distribution. However, does the parameter $\alpha$ mean that this is a sub-family of the power law distribution?

Comment: @user121049 Thanks. I've seen that but it doesn't help much. It is not a Pareto distribution (I've tried to see if it is a generalized Pareto distribution and it seem not).

Comment: It is a particular case of the Beta distribution, see the previous ref I gave where they mention this case. Some re-scaling has to be done to map the support onto 0-1.

Comment: Can you write an answer for it please? I also found it is a Power-law distribution with a certain parameterization. I will write an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis based on @alex's reply it seems the distribution is in fact a power law.

The power law distribution can be characterized as $f(x)=cx^{k}$ defined over the $[0,A]$ interval, where $A=\big(\frac{k+1}{c} \big)^{\frac{1}{k+1}}$

The function in my question is indeed a power law under the following parameterization:

- $k=\alpha+1$
- $c=\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{\big[H\big(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha}\big)\big]^{\alpha}}\bigg)$
- and so $A=H\big(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha}\big)$

If you replace these three expressions into the power law distribution given in this answer then you get the *pdf* from the original problem.